# How to design hibernate entity for parent child response in json format from single database table

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, spring-rest

I have database table

```
+-------------+----------------------+--------+
| category_id | name                 |parent_id  |
+-------------+----------------------+--------+
|           1 | ELECTRONICS          |   NULL |
|           2 | TELEVISIONS          |      1 |
|           3 | TUBE                 |      2 |
|           4 | LCD                  |      2 |
|           5 | PLASMA               |      2 |
|           6 | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS |      1 |
|           7 | MP3 PLAYERS          |      6 |
|           8 | FLASH                |      7 |
|           9 | CD PLAYERS           |      6 |
|          10 | 2 WAY RADIOS         |      6 |
+-------------+----------------------+--------+
```

and i designed hibernate entity this way but i am not able to get expected output which is mentioned in below json format:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
public class Category {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "category_id")
  private short categoryId;
  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;

  @Column(name = "parent_id")
  private Integer parentId;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
  private Set<Category> child;

  public short getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
  }

  public void setCategoryId(short categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
  }

  public String getName() {
        return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
  }

  public Integer getParentId() {
        return parentId;
  }

  public void setParentId(Integer parentId) {
        this.parentId = parentId;
  }

  public Set<Category> getChild() {
        return child;
  }

  public void setChild(Set<Category> child) {
        this.child = child;
  }
  }
```

Now i want response in below json format

```
[
{
"categoryId": 1,
"name": "ELECTRONICS",
"child": [
  {
    "categoryId": 2,
    "name": "TELEVISIONS",
    "child": [
      {
        "categoryId": 3,
        "name": "TUBE",
        "child": []
      },
      {
        "categoryId": 4,
        "name": "LCD",
        "child": []
      },
      {
        "categoryId": 5,
        "name": "PLASMA",
        "child": []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "categoryId": 6,
    "name": "PORTABLE ELECTRONICS",
    "child": [
      {
        "categoryId": 7,
        "name": "MP3 PLAYERS ",
        "child": [
          {
            "categoryId": 8,
            "name": "FLASH",
            "child": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "categoryId": 9,
        "name": "CD PLAYERS",
        "child": []
      },
      {
        "categoryId": 10,
        "name": "2 WAY RADIOS",
        "child": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
}
]
```

When i am trying to list category list using this code and sending response then i am getting below exception :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/fetchCategory", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public List<Category> fetchCategory() {
    List<Category> categories = null;
        try {
            categories = masterConfigurationService.fetchCategory();
        } catch (ServiceException e) {
              LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return categories;
  }
```

And DAO code is

```
session.createCriteria(Category.class).list();
```

UPDATE : 
- Updated entity - removed parent mapping from entity

Now i am getting parent tree two times if it is associated with two child.

Comment: Your mapping is just fine. Your two problems at the end of your questions are very vague.

Comment: @JBNizet i updated question and whenever i am trying to fetch list of category i am getting above mentioned exception.

Comment: This exception would happen with any lazy association: if you try to navigate through a not-loaded lazy association after the session has been closed, Hibernate can't initialize the lazy association, and thus throws that exception. Since you didn't post the code throwing that exception, not the complete stack trace, it's still hard to help.

Comment: @JBNizet i updated code which is generating exception.

Comment: Still no complete stack trace. I'll assume that this is caused by the JSON marshalling of the returned categories. There are several solutions: use a DTO (which will thus force you to initialize the lazy collections, and will enforece a clear separation between the objects returned by the service layer and the persistent entities), use an OpenEntityManagerInView filter/interceptor, navigate through the tree and thus initializing all the associations before returning the categories.